# jQuery menu script confusion

Tags: jquery

Well, I am not that good in jQuery, but at least I've tried to right a script by myself. 
So, here the thing.
I've got that navigation, with a "Services" button. When I hover over, the drop down menu appears, and in order not to distract users, "Main", "About" and "Contact" (.navigation__elem_mod-opa) change their style to opacity: .30.

But the deal is that - now, when the "Services" is hovered over, the opacity for those tags (.navigation__elem_mod-opa), should come back to normal (opacity: 1). Well, that's the problem. In this part I've got confused what to do next.

Thanks in advance!

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wMYQwG?editors=0010

```
$('li.navigation__elem.navigation__elem_mod-rel').hover(function() {
  $('.navigation__elem_mod-opa').css('opacity', '.30');
  $(this).children('ul').stop().fadeToggle('fast');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd separate it:

1. On hover, show the submenu.
2. On mouseover (which is like hover), add a class `opac` to all other `li` elements which is `opacity: .3;`
3. On mouseout, remove that class.

   ```
   $('li.navigation__elem.navigation__elem_mod-rel').hover(function() {
     $(this).children('ul').stop().fadeToggle('fast');
   });

   $('li.navigation__elem.navigation__elem_mod-rel').mouseover(function() {
     $('.navigation__elem_mod-opa').addClass('opac');
   });

   $('li.navigation__elem.navigation__elem_mod-rel').mouseout(function() {
     $('.navigation__elem_mod-opa').removeClass('opac');
   });
   ```

And a simple CSS rule:

```
li.opac {
  opacity: .3;
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NxOoJN)

Comment: Sorry Omri, but it won't work, cause after you hover on "Service" button, and move your pointer to sub-menu, you'll see a half a second blink of the main menu items because of some of the methods.

Comment: Omri, I've figured out! Thank you, bro. The blink thing worked cause of 'top' used in absolute positioning, instead of 'padding-top'!